# Amplify v6 IdentityPool IAM authentication

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-sdk-js

In Amplify V5 library, I was able to provide guest access to a GraphQL/App Sync api that I used in a registration user flow. To call the Appsync API as a guest, I would authenticate to using Cognito Identity pools and IAM auth.

This is how I would configure Amplify v5:

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

const amplifyConfig = {
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: 'identity-pool-id',
    region: 'region',
  },
  API: {
    graphql_headers: async () => {
      return {}
    }
  },
  aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint: 'graphql-endpoint',
  aws_appsync_region: 'region',
  aws_appsync_authenticationType: 'AWS_IAM',
};

Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
```

This is how I would sign in as guest, using AWS Cognito to authenticate as a guest. This was achieved by calling Auth.currentCredentials():

```
import { Auth } from '@aws-amplify';

export async function signInAsGuest() {
  try {
    await Auth.currentCredentials();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error signing in as a guest:', error);
  }
}
```

An this is how you would make the GraphQL call signed in to the identity pool, using IAM auth:

```
import { API, Auth } from '@aws-amplify';
import { signInAsGuest } from './auth/guest'
import { createUser } from './graphql/queries';

async function registerUser() {
  try {
    signInAsGuest();
    const response = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser));
    Auth.signOut();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}
```

This used to work fine. Now in v6, Auth.currentCredentials is [deprecated](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/auth-migration-guide/#authcurrentcredentials-deprecated). It suggests to use `fetchAuthSession` API. When I do, the result is an empty session object, and when I call the GraphQL API it returns:
`Error: No credentials`

This is the v6 code Im using to configure Amplify:

```js
export const appsyncGuestResourcesConfig = {
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      identityPoolId: 'identity-pool-id'
    }
  },
  API: {
    GraphQL: {
      endpoint: 'graphql-endpoint',
      defaultAuthMode: 'iam'
    }
  }
}

export const appsyncGuestLibraryOptions = {
  API: {
    GraphQL: {
      headers: async () => {
        return {}
      }
    }
  }
}

Amplify.configure(appsyncGuestResourcesConfig, appsyncGuestLibraryOptions)
```

This is how I'm trying to sign in as guest:

```js
import { fetchAuthSession } from '@aws-amplify/auth';

export async function signInAsGuest() {
  try {
    await fetchAuthSession();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error signing in as a guest:', error);
  }
}
```

As mentioned above, the result is an empty session object, and when I call the GraphQL API it returns:
`Error: No credentials.` I would appreciate help on how to achieve the above using v6 of Amplify.